# Java When using synchronized do I get volatile functionality for free?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized, volatile

I read several posts about concurrency problems but I'm still unsure about something. 
Can I say that when using synchronized, I get volatile functionality for free, because when the lock on an object will be released, the next thread always reads the modified object. With volatile, the value of an object is immediately reflected to other threads. But when I use synchronized, there is no possibility to immediately reflect it due to the lock on the object. When the lock is released, only then another thread may access it. So I don't have to care about reflecting the value immediately to other threads. Do I understand this right?

**[UPDATE]**
Example prints always 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 without volatile.

```
package main;

public class Counter
{
    public static long count = 0;
}

public class UseCounter implements Runnable
{
    public void increment()
    {
        synchronized (this)
        {       
            Counter.count++;
            System.out.print(Counter.count + " ");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        increment();
        increment();
        increment();
    }
}

public class DataRace
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        UseCounter c = new UseCounter();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(c);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(c);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(c);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: About your update: What it currently prints hardly means anything. Data race conditions typically sneak up when you least expect them and they're very hard to reproduce and resolve. What matters is if you have followed the rules of the Java Memory Model.

Comment: Ok thanks. Although I can't reproduce wrong behaviour without volatile (not even when I run the code 1.000.000 times in a loop), I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a volatile access is not implied by synchronized access according the the Java Memory Model (although on particular implementations, it may be, but you should not depend on that)

[Java Language Specification 17.4.4 (on the Java Memory Model):](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4)

> Synchronization actions induce the synchronized-with relation on
>   actions, defined as follows:
>
> - An unlock action on monitor m synchronizes-with all subsequent lock
>     actions on m (where "subsequent" is defined according to the
>     synchronization order).
> - A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) synchronizes-with all
>     subsequent reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined
>     according to the synchronization order).

`volatile` operates on a variable and `synchronized` operates on the monitor (the 'lock') of an object.

If one Thread A has just exited a synchronized block on object **O**, and another Thread B has just read a volatile variable (instance field) **V** on object **O**, then there is still **not** a synchronized-with relation between the two threads. There is no guarantee that Thread A will see any data modifications done by Thread B or vice versa, until Thread B also synchronized on object **O**, or until Thread A also accessed volatile field **V** on object **O**.

Comment: Ok, does that mean that I always should use volatile too when accessing external variables by several threads? Look my updated questions. It always prints 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 without volatile. So that means that it's not guaranteed to do so?

Comment: When one thread B reads (or writes) a volatile field after another thread A did that, then thread B will see *all* modifications that thread A made to any variable (before it accessed the same volatile field), including non-volatile ones. Accessing the same volatile variables creates a "happens-before" relation between the threads that did so.

Answer (score 1):

Having a volatile variable isn't the same as synchronized access. When you mark a variable as volatile, `Thread` objects accessing the object will not keep a local cache and there will only ever be one "copy". If you combine the two (synchronized and volatile) then it will always be the updated version, and you won't have conflicting access of it.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand why there is a conflicting access at all, because when I lock and release an object with synchronized, do I have to care if the first thread made a local copy of it? When the object is getting unlocked, isn't it then guaranteed that the next thread gains access to the modified object?

Comment: The idea behind `volatile` is that you will always get the most up-to-date version of the variable. When a thread keeps a cache it will do so in order to save time getting new values but volatile variables will not be cached

Answer (score 0):

Your code is guaranteed to print 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9. The reason is that if you have a sequence such as

1. Thread t1 writes to Counter.count
2. Thread t1 unlocks object c
3. Thread t2 locks object c
4. Thread t2 reads Counter.count

then it is guaranteed that the read at step 4 sees the write at step 1.

This is not the same as `volatile` because it is not guaranteed that the write is reflected back to memory immediately, rather it is only guaranteed that the write in step 1 is visible to t2 at the end of step 3.